# Ruby count # of matches in string from array

Tags: ruby

I have a string, for example:

```
'This is a test string'
```

and an array:

```
['test', 'is']
```

I need to find out how many elements in array are present in string (in this case, it would be 2). What's the best/ruby-way of doing this? Also, I am doing this thousands of time, so please keep in mind efficiency.

What I tried so far:

```
array.each do |el|
 string.include? el #increment counter
end
```

Thanks

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I looped through the array and used include? method.

Comment: What do you consider a match? For example, do you count "is" to be matched by the word "This" or do you only count full word matches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
['test', 'is'].count{ |s| /\b#{s}\b/ =~ 'This is a test string' }
```

**Edit:** adjusted for full word matching.

Comment: @0xSina you're welcome. Try [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) out.

Answer (score 3):

```
['test', 'is'].count { |e| 'This is a test string'.split.include? e }
```

Comment: It's `['test', 'is'].count { |e| 'This is a test string'.include? e }`, if u want to go down that road :)

Comment: Almost, he used regex to count the words.

Comment: That's the reason I find these algorithms fairly inefficient, regex more so than #include? variety, but it is of no consequence for small n.

Comment: The OP is trying to find full word occurrences and `String#include?` would not work for that. `'hello'.include?('hell') # => true`

Comment: @megas Yes. I was really commenting on Boris' "regex more so than #include" comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous.

If you are counting the occurrences, then:

```
('This is a test string'.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase) & ['test', 'is']).length
```

If you are counting the tokens, then:

```
(['test', 'is'] & 'This is a test string'.scan(/\w+/).map(&:downcase)).length
```

You can further speed up the calculation by replacing `Array#&` by some operation using a `Hash` (or `Set`).

Comment: While your answer is extremely interesting, the question is whether it is sufficiently general. What would happen if some of the match strings match the same word (not the case now, but could be in general)?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I think you are realizing the same amguity in the question as I did. See my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I never said it was your fault. But I must admit it, this question is an interesting refreshment from my boring programming task at hand today :)))

Answer (score 0):

Kyle's answer gave you the simple practical way of doing the job. But looking at it, allow me to remark that more efficient algorithms exist to solve your problem, when n (string length and/or number of matched strings) climbs to millions. We [commonly encounter such problems in biology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment).

Answer (score 0):

Following will work provided there are no duplicates in string or array.

```
str = "This is a test string"
arr = ["test", "is"]

match_count = arr.size - (arr - str.split).size # 2 in this example
```